# Sitecore Reload the Content Editor

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore, I am opening up a item in content editor using code and after user has done some changes I want to reload the content editor. I am trying to do this in Sitecore Item:Locked event handler and I am wondering whether I can raise a Sitecore event so the content editor would reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I think the `item:locked` might not be the right event for this, as you want to do it after the user has done changes. Have you looked at the `item:saved` event?

Secondly, I'm not entirely certain what it is you're trying to achieve. Is it that when any user makes a change, the instance of the content editor or someone else's machine needs to reload? I'm not sure that's possible. 
Or do you want a custom piece of code to run when the user has made a change, but then the user needs to have their own instance reloaded? 
If it's the latter, here's what you could try:

There's actually a couple of things you can do: 
**Reload item**
You can use something like the following to reload the item:

```
string load = String.Concat( new object[] { "item:load(id=", myItem.ID, ",language=", myItem.Language, ",version=", myItem.Version, ")" });
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load);
```

**Reload content editor**
If you do want to load the content editor up again, you could build the URL using something like:

```
string.Format("/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor.aspx
?id={0}&amp;fo={0}&amp;la={1}&amp;ver={2}", GUID of the item to be selected, 
Language you want to display, version you want to display);
```

Then you can either redirect the user to that page (using a simple `Response.Redirect`), or you can open op a new instance of the content editor (if you're in Desktop), for instance by using the `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Windows.RunApplication` method.

Comment: I wanted to reload the item and your approach worked for me. Thanks